# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Trying to access a field in parent class from inner class in child that is dynamically loaded

Tags: java, dynamic-class-loaders, illegalaccessexception

I'm trying to modify some existing code so I will be able to dynamically use a child class
to import data into my program.  However I have ran into a problem.  One of the classes I am trying to dynamically import contains two subclasses that access the abstract parent classes fields which cause java to throw an IllegalAccessError.  I've wrote a small test program to demonstrate the problem I am having.

The calling code creates URL class loader, loads the class, and then calls the do work method:

```
    URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    Class toLoad = Class.forName ("jarLoader.ChildClass", true, child);
    SuperClass sc = (SuperClass) toLoad.newInstance();
    sc.doWork();
```

The Parent class contains 3 int fields and an abstract method:

```
package jarLoader;

public abstract class SuperClass {


protected int a = 1;
protected int b = 2;
protected int c = 3;


public SuperClass(){
}

public abstract void doWork();

}
```

The child class,  When do work is called it creates the inner class and tries to access the parents data feild and an exception is thrown:
       package jarLoader;

public class ChildClass extends SuperClass {

```
@Override
public void doWork() {
    NestedClass c = new NestedClass();
    c.go();
}

class NestedClass{


    private void go(){
        int val = a;
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}


}
```

The error occurs only after I export the child class as a jar and run the program loading the jar at runtime.

Comment: I suspect that you're getting one of your classes loaded twice, by two different class loaders.

Comment: (But Java inner classes are a hack anyway, so it could just be a bug, er, "feechure".)

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/protected

> This keyword is an access modifier, used before a method or other class member to signify that the method or variable can only be accessed by elements residing in its own class or classes in the same package (as it would be for the default visibility level) but moreover from subclasses of its own class, including subclasses in foreign packages (if the access is made on an expression, whose type is the type of this subclass).

As soon as you load it from a jar, it actually extends a copy of the parent (from what I understand, that is). Therefore it can't access the protected elements of the real parent. Have you tried setting a to public, or creating a public getter?